# Encoding of non-ascii file names

Tags: dropzone.js

For uploads with drop zone.js, file names containing non-ascii characters will  not be encoded before sent to the server. They are just left as they are:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryvXgdeNXSwHZBUrFJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[0]"; filename="täst.png"
```

As a result, on server-side encoding is unknown.

Is there a way to force dropzone.js to UrlEncode the filename, similar to RFC 6266?

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[0]"; filename*=utf-8''t%c3%a4st.png
```

Or is there any other solution?

Comment: how do you enforce that the file's contents are enforced to be UTF-8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and what I ended up doing to solve this was to pass an additional parameter.

```
$("#myDz").dropzone({
    init: function () {
        this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
            var fn = encodeURI(file.name)
            formData.append("encFilename", fn);
        });
    }
});
```

This will send the additional parameter `encFilename` to the backend which can then be used to name the file when it's written to disk. `file.name` can't be updated at that point but doing it like this works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

IamNaN's solution works fine. Just need to decode in Java WS:

```
 filename = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(filename, "UTF-8");
```